# How to prevent long strings from being written to resx file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, designer, resx

Even though my form is not set to be localized, Visual Designer puts text into the .resx instead of directly in the code if I have a label whose text is over 200 characters long.

This is problem because I am using a custom localization approach that pulls localizable strings from the code, but it doesn't search resx files.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior? I can just hard-code the string in my code so the extractor can get it, but this is annoying because the text looks wrong in Designer. Alternatively, I could use multiple labels, but that just feels wrong.

I've seen other people asking a similar questions in other forums, but no answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete solution, but it is possible to scan the resources associated with a type and find the strings that the designer has decided to do this to.

```
            var resources = new ResourceManager(type);
            using (var set = resources.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true, false))
            {
                if (set != null)
                {
                    foreach (DictionaryEntry res in set)
                    {
                        var key = res.Key as string;
                        var val = res.Value as string;
                        if (key == null || val == null)
                            continue;
                        if (!key.EndsWith(".Text"))
                            continue;
                        key = key.Substring(0, key.Length - ".Text".Length);
                        // key is now the name of your control
                        // val is the string the designer stored as its Text in the default resource
                    }
                }
            }
```